# Python Object inheritance

Tags: python, object, inheritance

```py
class Phone:
   def install():
        ...

class InstagramApp(Phone):
    ...

def install_app(phone: "Phone", app_name):
   phone.install(app_name)

app = InstagramApp()
install_app(app, 'instagram') # <--- is that OK ?
```

`install_app` gets a `Phone` object.
will it work with with InstagramApp object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance works correctly. `install` method is inherited from `Phone` class. But your code doesn't work. When you run it, it will say:

```
TypeError: Phone.install() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

What are these two arguments that have been passed?

Second one is obviously the `'instagram'` string. You passed that but no parameter expects it.

The first one is, Because you invoke that `install()` method from an instance, Python turns it into a "Method" and automatically fills the first parameter of it to a reference to the instance(this is how [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) work). But again you don't have any parameter to receive it.

To make that work:

```py
class Phone:
    def install(self, name):
        print(self)
        print(name)


class InstagramApp(Phone):
    ...


def install_app(phone: "Phone", app_name):
    phone.install(app_name)


app = InstagramApp()
install_app(app, "instagram")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not filling all the functions parameters as it is not the main Q in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, methods are also inherited from classes. However, you will need to add a parameter to the `install` method so it can take the app name:

```py
class Phone:
   def install(self, app_name):  # Allow the method to take an input app name
        ...

class InstagramApp(Phone):
    ...

def install_app(phone: "Phone", app_name):
   phone.install(app_name)

app = InstagramApp()
install_app(app, 'instagram')  # Yes, this will also work with the InstagramApp class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - so long as the InstagramApp doesn't delete any of the methods that 'install_app', and the methods return the same types as the Phone class does then it will work.

I am curious as to why to pass the instance and pass the name as text - you could accomplish the sanme by simply ascessing the `__name__` variable of the class - so for instance :

```
`app.__class_.__name__ will equal 'Instagram'
```

As others have pointed out you need to fix the various function calls.

Answer (score 0):

install_app gets a Phone object. will it work with InstagramApp object?
the inheritance class will have the function

```
class Phone:
   def install(app_name:str):# change type to str
       pass
    

class InstagramApp(Phone):
    pass

def install_app(phone: Phone, app_name):# change the type to Phone Class
   phone.install(app_name)

app = InstagramApp()
install_app(app, 'instagram') #
```

Comment: You still need `self`(or any other name) parameter in `install` method.